Python - unable to decode SQLite Blob
I have a Database with BLOB in it. I tryed to read and save in file it but it didnt work. Then i just write raw bytes and get it
b'\xcb\xd2\x00\xd2N\xa9}s\xc7\xc2\x8f\x02n\x11\xc2\xee\xb2s \x93&\xe6u\x97\xe9@\xba'

I try to decode it with any encoding scheme but it also didn't work. This BLOB must contain some test files.
How to get it?
Code to convert to file:
def writeTofile(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(data)
    print("Stored blob data into: ", filename, "\n")

Code to decode data from BLOB(after extraction):
try:
    decoded_text = decoded_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    print("Decoded as UTF-8:", decoded_text)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print("Failed to decode as UTF-8")


Looks like UTF-16 for Korean "It's like a dog. It's like a dog."

Does you actual byte string have that space in it? If you remove that space then .decode("UTF-16") gives "틋툀ꥎ獽싇ʏᅮ玲⚓痦멀"
